# Multi level Marketing stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

[Tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlGB9.png)
I want to create a multilevel tree structure for user Registration , a members can add up to 5 members if he adds another member which greater than the limit it should be added as the first child member. for example as in the figure tree Image, 1 can directly add members 2,3,4,5,6 if 1 add a member again it should be added as the first child of 2,and if 1 add again it should be added as the first child of 3 and so on up to first child of 6, then if one again adds it should be the second child of 2, again second child of 3 and so on how can i create a stored procedure to insert into my user table which automatically perform this here i am attaching my table structure also

Here I am attaching the table how can i achieve this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Login_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Login_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Login_Password] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Referal_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [User_Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [BankName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [IFSC] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [AccountNo] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [Created_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Modified_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Login_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [UnsuscribeEmail] [int] NULL,
    [UnsuscribeSms] [int] NULL,
    [IsBanned] [int] NULL,
    [ISDeleted] [int] NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Login_ID] ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: your question is too braod. Post a working code sample and explain where it's failing. Then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [Hyperbole]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Users]    Script Date: 9/26/2016 1:22:23 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [Login_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Login_Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Login_Password] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [bigint] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [bigint] NULL,
    [Referal_ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [User_Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [BankName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AccountName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [IFSC] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [AccountNo] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [Created_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Modified_Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Last_Login_Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [UnsuscribeEmail] [int] NULL,
    [UnsuscribeSms] [int] NULL,
    [IsBanned] [int] NULL,
    [ISDeleted] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Login_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[User_SP]
(
           @Login_Name nvarchar(100)=null
           ,@Login_Password nvarchar(100)=null
           ,@CreatedBy BIGINT=null
           ,@ModifiedBy BIGINT=null
           ,@Referal_ID BIGINT=null
           ,@Name nvarchar(250)=null
           ,@User_Address nvarchar(max)=null
           ,@Phone nvarchar(14)=null
           ,@Email nvarchar(250)=null
           ,@BankName nvarchar(250)=null
           ,@AccountName nvarchar(250)=null
           ,@IFSC nvarchar(250)=null
           ,@AccountNo nvarchar(150)=null
           ,@DOB datetime=null
           ,@Created_Date datetime=null
           ,@Modified_Date datetime=null
           ,@Last_Login_Date_Time datetime=null
           ,@UnsuscribeEmail int=0
           ,@UnsuscribeSms int=0
           ,@IsBanned int=0
           ,@ISDeleted int=0
           )
--@UserName     NVARCHAR (255),
--@parentID BIGINT
as
begin

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ChildHierarchy') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ChildHierarchy

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ChildCount') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #ChildCount

CREATE TABLE #ChildHierarchy ( ChildId BIGINT, ChildName NVARCHAR(255), LevelNo BIGINT, ParentID BIGINT )

CREATE TABLE #ChildCount ( ChildParentID BIGINT, ChildCount BIGINT, ChildParentLevelID BIGINT, MaxChildCount BIGINT, AvailableChildCount BIGINT )

DECLARE @MaxChildCount TABLE ( LevelID INT, MaxChildCount BIGINT )

DECLARE  @NextParentID BIGINT, @MaxLevelNo INT 

INSERT INTO @MaxChildCount (LevelID, MaxChildCount)
VALUES ( 1, 5 ), ( 2, 25 ), ( 3, 125 ), ( 4, 625 ), ( 5, 3125 ), ( 6, 15625 ), ( 7, 78125 ), ( 8, 390625 ), ( 9, 1953125 ), ( 10, 9765625 )

/*row generations*/
;WITH Hierarchy(ChildId, ChildName, LevelNo, ParentId)
AS
(
    SELECT Login_ID, Name, 0, Referal_ID
        FROM Users AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE Login_ID = @Referal_ID        
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.Login_ID, NextGeneration.Name, Parent.LevelNo + 1, Parent.ChildId
        FROM Users AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.Referal_ID = Parent.ChildId    
)

INSERT INTO #ChildHierarchy (ChildId,ChildName,LevelNo,ParentID)
SELECT ChildId, ChildName, LevelNo, ParentId
    FROM Hierarchy
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)

INSERT INTO #ChildCount (ChildParentID, ChildCount,ChildParentLevelID)
SELECT ParentID, COUNT(ChildId), LevelNo 
FROM #ChildHierarchy 
WHERE LevelNo > 0
GROUP BY ParentID, LevelNo

UPDATE CC SET MaxChildCount = MCC.MaxChildCount
FROM #ChildCount CC
INNER JOIN @MaxChildCount MCC ON CC.ChildParentLevelID = MCC.LevelID


SET @MaxLevelNo = ( SELECT MAX(LevelNo) FROM #ChildHierarchy )

UPDATE CC SET AvailableChildCount = CC1.AvailableChildCount 
FROM #ChildCount CC
INNER JOIN ( SELECT ChildParentLevelID,SUM(ChildCount) AS AvailableChildCount FROM #ChildCount GROUP BY ChildParentLevelID ) CC1 ON CC.ChildParentLevelID = CC1.ChildParentLevelID

IF @MaxLevelNo = 0 OR NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #ChildCount )
    SET @NextParentID = @Referal_ID

IF @NextParentID IS NULL 
    SET @NextParentID = ( SELECT MIN(ChildParentID) FROM #ChildCount WHERE MaxChildCount <> AvailableChildCount AND ChildCount <> 5 )

IF @NextParentID IS NULL
    SET @NextParentID = ( SELECT MIN(CH.ChildId) FROM #ChildHierarchy CH WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #ChildCount CC WHERE CH.ChildId = CC.ChildParentID ) )

INSERT INTO Users (Login_Name,Login_Password,CreatedBy,ModifiedBy,Referal_ID,Name,User_Address,Phone,Email,BankName,AccountName,IFSC,AccountNo,DOB,Created_Date,Modified_Date,UnsuscribeEmail,UnsuscribeSms,IsBanned,ISDeleted)
SELECT @Login_Name,@Login_Password,@NextParentID,@NextParentID,@NextParentID,@Name,@User_Address,@Phone,@Email,@BankName,@AccountName,@IFSC,@AccountNo,@DOB,@Created_Date,@Modified_Date,0,0,0,0

end
GO
```